# How to add numbering to reference list but still use authoryear in natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Is there an easy way to add numbers to the reference list generated by `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` with whatever style file (using `plainnat` for ease)? Specifically, I use `\cite` and `\citenum` from `natbib` in order to have some references show up in the text as author-year and others just appear as numbers. Switching `authoryear` out for `numbers` in the `natbib` options generates a reference list with numbered references, but also causes the references in the text to all appear as numbers, which I don't want.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\cite{A} said this, but other research \citenum{B,C} says otherwise.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{MalariaBib,MST}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Setting the citation style to `numbers` before the `\bibliography` will produce a reference list with numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\cite{A} % This citation should be in author-year style.

\setcitestyle{numbers} % set the citation style to ``numbers''.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{MalariaBib,MST} % now the reference list has numbers
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and `\citet{}` for references to be printed as authoryear in the text (and `\citenum` for just numbers, but I guess the num can be dropped now) produces approximately the desires effect.